# Custom iterator returns empty array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why is the result empty?

```
var myDogs = function(dogs) { 
 this.dogs = dogs;
 this[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
   let i = -1;
   return {    
    next() {
     i++;
     let j = 0;
     var dog = void(0);
     for (var dog in this.dogs) {
       if (j == i) {
        dog = { dog, hungry: dogs[dog] };
        break;
       } 
       j++;
     }
     var done = !dog;
     return { value: dog, done };
    }
   };
 };
};

var dogs = new myDogs({ buddy: true, hasso: false });
var dogHungryMap = [...dogs];
> dogHungryMap = [];
```

Seems like I haven't grasped the concept of iterators or I am doing a totally stupid mistake. The expected result is `[{ dog: 'buddy', hungry: true }, { dog: 'hasso': hungry: false }]`.

http://www.es6fiddle.net/ije6visa/

Comment: Instead of `var dogHungryMap = [...myDogs];`, it should probably be `var dogHungryMap = [...dogs];`, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two bugs in your code:

- `this`, in your `next` function, is the iterator, not the instance of `myDogs`.
- `dog` is both the key in your iteration and the result. Which means `dog` is **never** `undefined` at the end of the iteration. You should probably be more careful with the semantic of your variable names.

Solving these two problems gives this:

```
var myDogs = function(dogs) {  
 this.dogs = dogs; 
 let _this = this; 
 this[Symbol.iterator] = function() { 
   let i = -1; 
   return {     
    next() { 
     i++; 
     let j = 0; 
     var dog = void(0); 
     for (var dogName in _this.dogs) { 
       if (j == i) { 
        dog = { dog:dogName, hungry: _this.dogs[dogName] }; 
        break; 
       }  
       j++; 
     } 
     var done = !dog; 
     return { value: dog, done }; 
    } 
   }; 
 }; 
};
```

But there's a simpler solution:

```
var myDogs = function(dogs) {
 this[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
   let i = -1;
   return {
    next() {
     i++;
     var dog = Object.keys(dogs)[i];
     if (!dog) return {done:true};
     return {value:{ dog, hungry:dogs[dog] }, done:false};
    }
   };
 };
};
```

Side note: there's no reason to use `void(0)` today.