# Understanding implementing custom iterators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand Ecmascript 6 iterators and trying to create a data structure which behaves much like native Arrays.

```
for (let i of [1,2,3]) console.log(i);  //Iterate over data set itself
```

will output `1,2,3`

```
for (let i of [1,2,3].keys()) console.log(i); //Iterate over a custom iterator from a method
```

will output `0,1,2`, and

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var keys = [...a.keys()];
```

will contain `[0,1,2]` as expected.

Therefore,

```
console.log([1,2,3].keys().next());
```

will output `Object {value: 0, done: false}`

Now I created a new type of data and tried to make it behave the same way.

```
var myDogs = function(dogs) {
 this.dogs = dogs;
 this[Symbol.iterator] = () => {
   let i = -1;
   return {
    next() {
     i++;
     var dog = Object.keys(dogs)[i];
     if (!dog) return {done:true};
     return {value:{ dog, hungry:dogs[dog] }, done:false};
    }
   };
 };
 this.dogsNames = () => {
  return {
   [Symbol.iterator]() {
     let i = -1;
     return {
      next() {
       i++;
       var dog = Object.keys(dogs)[i];
       if (!dog) return {done:true};
       return {value: dog, done:false};
      }
     };
   }
  }
 }
};

var dogs = new myDogs({ buddy: true, hasso: false });
```

This works as expected (a custom iterator - [thank you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788685/custom-iterator-returns-empty-array)):

```
var dogHungryMap = [...dogs];
dogHungryMap == [{ dog: 'buddy', hungry: true }, { dog: 'hasso': hungry: false }]
```

The iterator `dogsNames()` works **almost** as expected. This is OK:

```
var names = [...dogs.dogsNames()];
names == ["buddy", "hasso"]
```

But this does not:

```
dogs.dogsNames().next()
VM19728:2 Uncaught TypeError: dogs.dogsNames(...).next is not a function(…)
```

*Why and how can I reproduce the behavior of native arrays?*

Comment: Just FYI, native arrays work the same way. There is no `Array.prototype.next()` method, it's only available through `arrayVar[Symbol.iterator]().next()` too

Comment: `dogNames` has to return an iterator that is also an iterable (and returns itself). Every built-in iterator does that: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-%iteratorprototype%-object .  Quick test: v`ar it = [].keys(); it[Symbol.iterator]() === it` results in `true`. So basically: `return {next() { ... }, [Symbol.iterator]() { return this; }};`.

Comment: @FelixKling this indeed answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dogNames` has to return an iterator (something that implements a `next` method) that is also an iterable (something that implements a `Symbol.iterator` method) (and returns itself). [Every built-in iterator does that](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-%iteratorprototype%-object).

A quick test verifies that:

```
var it = [].keys();
it[Symbol.iterator]() === it // true
```

So you could change your code to

```
this.dogsNames = () => {
  let i = -1;
  return {

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
      return this;
    },

    next() {
      i++;
      var dog = Object.keys(dogs)[i]; // should probably also be put in the outer function
      if (!dog) return {done:true};
      return {value: dog, done:false};
    },

  };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `dogsNames()` returns an object which has an iterator as a key. So you can use `for...of` over dogsNames, but to access `next()` directly you need to access the iterator function declared on the object like so:

```
dogsNames()[Symbol.iterator]().next()
```

[Babel REPL Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20myDogs%20%3D%20function(dogs)%20%7B%0A%20this.dogs%20%3D%20dogs%3B%0A%20this%5BSymbol.iterator%5D%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20let%20i%20%3D%20-1%3B%0A%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20next()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20i%2B%2B%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20var%20dog%20%3D%20Object.keys(dogs)%5Bi%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!dog)%20return%20%7Bdone%3Atrue%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bvalue%3A%7B%20dog%2C%20hungry%3Adogs%5Bdog%5D%20%7D%2C%20done%3Afalse%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%7D%3B%0A%20this.dogsNames%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%5BSymbol.iterator%5D()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20let%20i%20%3D%20-1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20next()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20i%2B%2B%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20dog%20%3D%20Object.keys(dogs)%5Bi%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!dog)%20return%20%7Bdone%3Atrue%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bvalue%3A%20dog%2C%20done%3Afalse%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Avar%20dogList%20%3D%20new%20myDogs(%7B%0A%20%20dog1%3A%20%22dog1%22%0A%7D)%3B%0Afor(const%20x%20of%20dogList.dogsNames())%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(x)%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log(dogList.dogsNames()%5BSymbol.iterator%5D().next()))

And for completeness, the full code for sharing next() function:

```
var myDogs = function(dogs) {
 this.dogs = dogs;
 let i = -1;
 var iter = {
   next() {
     i++;
     var dog = Object.keys(dogs)[i];
     if (!dog) return {done:true};
     return {value:{ dog, hungry:dogs[dog] }, done:false};
   }
 }
 this[Symbol.iterator] = () => iter;
 this.next = iter.next;
};
var dogList = new myDogs({
  dog1: "no",
  dog2: "yes"
});
for(const x of dogList) console.log(x);
console.log(dogList.next());
console.log(dogList.next());
```

Comment: Ok and how can I reproduce the behavior of native arrays?

Comment: With regards to an iterator? That's already what you have done more or less. [Babel REPL for arrays](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20arr%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%3B%0Aconsole.log(arr%5BSymbol.iterator%5D().next()))

Comment: In other words: how can I keep the spread operator working and make `dogsNames().next()` work AS WELL?

Comment: @BarthZalewski You need to share the `next()` method between the class and the iterator in some way...[Like this](http://bit.ly/1PZXOC6)